# How to fix indentation errors?

Tags: python

I am getting an indentation error. I have already tried converting all tabs to spaces with my code editor and using autopep8

I am getting the following error:

```
return (imgstring)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Below is the code:

```
def Barchart(id, title, data):

    bar_chart = pygal.Bar()
    bar_chart.title = title

    data_cols = data.split(':')
    for x in range(0, len(data_cols)):
        data_num = []
        data_cols_split = data_cols[x].split(',')

        for y in range(1, len(data_cols_split)):
            print(data_cols_split[y])
            data_num.append(int(data_cols_split[y]))

        bar_chart.add(str(data_cols_split[0]), data_num)

    bar_chart.render_to_png('barchart.png')


s3 = session.resource('s3')
data = open('barchart.png', 'rb')
amazonname = str(id) + '.png'
s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=amazonname, Body=data)
data.close()
with open("barchart.png", "rb") as imageFile:
  imgstring = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())



 return (imgstring)
```

Comment: Indent properly...

Comment: i cant figure it out...

Comment: You can see quite clearly that `return` is not in-line with `with`. Also, the error doesn't just say "the indentation is wrong", it points to the exact line it's unhappy about in the traceback.

Comment: when i align it with 'with' I get 
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: Because you have lines in-line with `def` but everything inside the function body should also be indented

Comment: I get IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix indentation to be inline with your code. Check [this page out](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for python indentation best practices.

```
def Barchart(id, title, data):

    bar_chart = pygal.Bar()
    bar_chart.title = title

    data_cols = data.split(':')
    for x in range(0, len(data_cols)):
        data_num = []
        data_cols_split = data_cols[x].split(',')

        for y in range(1, len(data_cols_split)):
            print(data_cols_split[y])
            data_num.append(int(data_cols_split[y]))

        bar_chart.add(str(data_cols_split[0]), data_num)

    bar_chart.render_to_png('barchart.png')


    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    data = open('barchart.png', 'rb')
    amazonname = str(id) + '.png'
    s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=amazonname, Body=data)
    data.close()
    with open("barchart.png", "rb") as imageFile:
        imgstring = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())



    return (imgstring)
```